# EF Core - multiple repository functions for Read

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, repository

I'm trying to optimize repositories in a .net projects that use a global 'Read' function. Currently, everything is done through a single 'Read' function. What I want to achieve are separate, multiple Read functions, with only the requested columns. The problem with this is - the table I'm working with has 49 columns, so selecting only a few columns per function results in a LOT of new functions.

This is how the current read functions looks. This essentially reads all columns even if need only some.

```
public BookDto ReadById(int id)
{
  var query =
      from b in _context.Instance.Books
      where b.Book_id == id
      select b
      
  return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

What I started implementing were LINQ queries using the Select method, to only select specific columns, like so:

```
public string ReadNameById(int id)
{
      var query =
          from b in _context.Instance.Books
          where b.Book_id == id
          select b.Book_name
          
      return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or if I need multiple properties:

```
public BookDto ReadNameIdById(int id)
{
      var query =
          from b in _context.Instance.Books
          where b.Book_id == id
          select new BookDto
          {
            Book_id  = b.Book_id ,
            Book_name = b.Book_name
          };
          
      return query.FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

The requests I have are for different columns, and very often read 2-5 columns out of the 49. Implementing every request with different select DTOs would result in ~30 functions just for Read. Is this the right way to go, or is there a simpler, more clean way to only read some columns, but keep the repository clean?

Comment: Do you happen to use something like Automapper, too? If so, you may be interested in its `ProjectTo<T>` functionality.

Comment: Btw: `select b.Name` vs `Book_name = b.Book_name` <- maybe recheck column names?

Comment: @Fildor Automapper is not used. It's a hypothetical example, hence the mistake :-)

Comment: Don't do it; you're needlessly heading down the road of reimplementing something EF/C# already does and gradually your Read method will become a pointless replication of Enumerable that just causes you pain. Update all the call sites to run their own queries, or return the queryable for the call site to finish off with only the props it wants

Comment: ^^ _"finish off with only the props it wants"_ - which is basically "projection".

Comment: Agree with @HasBeanCounter . This is one of several reasons why repository pattern with EF Core is needlessly redundant. If you absolutely must keep the repository, you could have a function that returns `IQueryable<Book>` and let the caller do its own projection.

Comment: @Luke I was thinking something similar, one Read function with a parameter for properties to be read, but I couldn't come up with a good enough repo implementation. Anything specific I can search to see some examples on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure you caught the gist of what we were saying. If you return `IQueryable<Book>` from your repo method, your controller endpoints (or whatever is calling your repo) can just include your properties there. You could have a parameter of something like `Expression<Func<Book, bool>>[] includes` but that's still going to be limiting when you want to include properties of collection navigations, etc. Just return the `IQueryable` and let the caller do the rest